# How can I block ICMP/PING/Traceroute on Mac OSX Server?

Tags: macos, mac, unix, ping, icmp

I understand that on Linux I do:

```
// allow
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
// block
echo 0 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all

// permanent block (edit /etc/sysctl.conf)
net.ipv4.conf.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
```

But what about on my Mac Mini OSX Server?

Comment: Why in the world do people block ping and traceroute? ._.

Comment: Ask the admins of microsoft.com

Comment: @AnonymousLurker, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ipfw should do the trick for you:

```
sudo ipfw -f add deny icmp from any to any in
```

It worked on my 10.6.8 installation, anyhow.

Alternatively you could turn on Stealth Mode as described here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1810

Comment: I ran this on my server and then tried to ping it remotely (`ping server.name`) and it pinged just fine.  Do I need to restart or logout to activate the change?  After your command above it read: `65534 deny icmp from any to any in`

Comment: No, it should be instantaneous. Perhaps there is an earlier rule which was explicitly allowing it? Can you grab your existing firewall rules  related to icmp and post them here? Like ``sudo ipfw list |grep icmp``

Comment: What was the output of ``sudo ipfw list |grep icmp`` ?

Comment: `12309 allow icmp from any to any icmptypes 8` and `12310 allow icmp from any to any icmptypes 0`

Comment: There you go - that rule explicitly allows icmp traffic, so the denial rule never gets hit. Try ``sudo ipfw delete 12309`` and then ``sudo ipfw -f add deny icmp from any to any in`` again, and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Nate, but still no luck.  I deleted 12309 & 12310, reran the grep icmp to confirm, and then reran the deny.  Still no change.

Comment: Maybe there's an even broader rule, let's see the full glory of ipfw's configuration then? ``ipfw list``